# How to update or remove existing subscriber via Store APIS in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working on WSO2 API Manager, version 1.6 and 1.8. I have created a new subscriber via Store APIs, and i don't see that there is supported to update or remove existing subscriber. Does WSO2 API Manager still not support that ?

Thanks,

An

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block the existing subscription form the publisher @ subscriptions menu.

Comment: Hi Ratha, thanks for giving to me an answer. I am going to try to remove  subscription by using Store APIs